# HTML content Column Headers: Repeating Column headers for every row?

Tags: html, powerbi, dax

I am trying to Create an HTML Table using a measure as my values input for the HTML Content Visual.

The problem I am encountering is that I see my column headers repeating for every row I have when I add a measure for the granularity of the data.
Most Solutions online are quite outdated and tell me to input the Header with column names within the Formatting sections in the Visualizations Pane, however this is not available within the HTML Content Visual anymore.

Has anyone else come across this issue and found a work around so that the column headers are not repeated for every row?

I have tried the basic blocking in HTML format, separating the column headers from the body data.

Thanks in advance!

[Link to Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZDXP.png)

Comment: Do  you have a screenshot of the problem, perhaps?

Comment: @KerimGüney sure! Screenshot attached in the post above!